# Blackberry APN Setting

Tags: blackberry

I have downloaded some Applications from Blackberry AppWorld and they run without the need to set APN setting, all the apps the client server based. But when I install my app(the jad file) via OTA into the device,its ask for APN settings to run my app.

If i set the APN,it executes fine,but i want it to execute without setting the APN like other apps are working. I have also set in the Connector.open(url +";deviceside=false"),still no success.My device is 8520 4.6.1.Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Are you a member of the BlackBerry Alliance Program?  It is possible that the vendors of the other apps are members and so have access to BIS connections, while if you are not, your app will not have access to BIS connections, thus requiring the APN settings for a direct connection.